# can I cache a kiesession in drools expert?

Tags: drools, jboss-rules

I have a large set of rules and when I execute

KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession(sessionName);

It takes a long time. I would like to reuse the kiesession. How is it possible to do that?
My input records come one at a time and not in a batch.

There is very little documentation available. .

Comment: Why don't you keep the session? Remove all facts (the fact) from it, and it will be as good as new.

Comment: @user1456599 have you find a way to re use kie sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code.
I think this might be useful for some one else.
I found that when I have to process a large batch 
then the best way is to process a bunch of records at a time if possible.
and then cache the kiesession.(Do not call dispose.!!)
Just remove the fact handles after the set is done.

`List<FactHandle> fhs = new ArrayList<FactHandle>();//store the fact handles

//for removing later

.....in a loop add one or multiple records

....

fhs.add(ksession.insert(prcRec));`

..............................

```
for (FactHandle factHandle : fhs) {
            ksession.delete(factHandle);
        }//Delete the fact handles so that next batch can be handled
```